# openssl req sets wrong "not after" date (overflow bug?)

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I tried to gernerate my own root CA with a validity of 40 years as follow: `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -days 10950 -extensions v3_ca -keyout myca.key -out myca.crt -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

So far so good, finally let's take a look at the certificate with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in myca.crt`:

```
   Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=DE, ST=Berlin, L=Berlin, O=Org, OU=Unit, CN=My Root CA/emailAddress=info@my.root.ca
    Validity
        Not Before: Jan 31 14:07:06 2012 GMT
        Not After : Dec 18 07:38:50 1905 GMT
```

**Why is the valid to date (not after date) wrong in the certificate?** And what can be done to correct this?

---

Some testing showed, that the overflowing occurs somewhere in January 2038..

Comment: I noticed that too, but on another platform: pfSense 2.x GUI. When creating a CA with a lifetime above 30y the expiration date will be 1.1.1970. Just to say this might be a generic OpenSSL bug/feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem: (keywords "openssl time_t 32bit")

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/SSL_in_The_Year2038

The "fix" in my opinion is to generate your CA on a system with 64-bit OpenSSL.

Comment: i've just created my cert on a 64-bit OS :-)